# Why isn’t “reasonable” used in “The landlords raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and REASONABLY so”?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Could somebody explain me why we use *reasonably* instead of *reasonable*:

> The landlords raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and **reasonably** so.

Quite confuse this grammar.

Comment: Adjectivally, raising the rent was ***reasonable***. Adverbially, we'd often include an "intensifier", such as ***very, quite*** - which in a less "florid, poetic" word order might be expressed as *The landlord **quite reasonably** raised the rent*.

Comment: Your *specific* example is a bit "literary / florid", but it's perfectly natural even in relaxed speech to use this construction in contexts such as *X did Y, and **rightly** so* (speaker thinks that Y was the right thing for X to do).

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence:

> The landlord raised the monthly rent for the first time in several
>   years, and REASONABLY so...

may be an idiomatic.

"reasonably" may also modify "and so", depending on context.

Examples:

1. The landlord raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and so, the tenants were unhappy.

"and so" is a conjunction that describes whatever comes after depends on and is affected by whatever comes before.

2. The landlord raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and reasonably so, the tenants were unhappy.

This is like the above example, but the speaker is agreeing or empathizing with the tenant's unhappiness.

3. The landlord raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and reasonably so!

This is an idiomatic use. It means that the speaker empathizes with or agrees with the landlord's decision.

Comment: I confuse the pharase REASONABLY SO because I dont know its meaning. Could you explain it again sit

Comment: It depends on the context. Sometimes, "thus" or "therefore" is the meaning. Sometimes, it is used to express that the speaker is agreeing with the statement.

Comment: so This example AND SO is repeat the full sentences and that act REASONABLY right, Sir?

Comment: @farm4fame I edited my response.

Comment: I understand clearly now. Thank you my teacher. How can I vote you. I did but error need 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

What would "reasonable" modify?

In the phrasing "and reasonably so", I understand the word "so" to represent the earlier phrase "raised the monthly rent".

> The landlords raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and reasonably so. 
>   The landlords raised the monthly rent for the first time in several years, and raised it reasonably.

The adverb "reasonably" works with a verb like "raised" or a complete predicate like "raised the monthly rent".   It still works well when the anaphor "so" represents that kind of thing.

Adjectives like "reasonable", on the other hand, tend to work with nouns.   I can't spot any noun or noun-like thing which the adjective "reasonable" might modify.